# Loop on SELECT single column id

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get the syntax of loop on a results of "single ID column SELECT query".

My goal is, each time the loop spin to get the current Id number

The query is something like that:

```
SELECT Id FROM tbl WHERE SomeField = "Something"
```

lets say the results are: 33 , 48 , 76

I want to loop on this results so every spin I will have a variable with the current number Id

```
Start Loop
     @CurrentId = ???
End Loop
```

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: Iterative tasks are rarely the right choice in an RDBMS. What is your actual goal here? I doubt a loop is the right answer.

Comment: this is part of SP and in the middle of the loop I have 200 lines of code that calls another SP and all happens on this ID.

Comment: You  *could* use a CURSOR to do this, however this should be your last resort (if ever)

Comment: You have 200 lines of code to call another SP? Might be time to step back and reevaluate your process. Something sounds like it has gone a bit left of center.

Comment: Ok but what is the syntax of the CURSOR and most important: how do I return after every spin the CurrentId, I'm new with SQL but I think I know what I'm doing...

Comment: If you can't look for the syntax to write a CURSOR, I would argue against your statement mentioning that you know what you're doing. Most people that are new to SQL will use iterative code instead of the better option of set-based code. In the end, you might have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, it's not a good idea to use a RDMBS to work row by row, but hey:

```
DECLARE @id INT;
SELECT TOP 1 @id = id FROM tbl WHERE SomeField = 'Something' ORDER BY id;
WHILE @id IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    --Do stuff with @id
    DECLARE @old_id INT;
    SELECT @old_id = @id;
    SELECT @id = NULL;
    SELECT TOP 1 @id = id FROM tbl WHERE SomeField = 'Something' AND id > @old_id ORDER BY id;
END;
```

---

Or I might consider doing this, as it's a little cleaner in some ways:

```
CREATE TABLE #loop_ids (
    loop_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    id INT);
INSERT INTO #loop_ids (id) SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE SomeField = 'Something' ORDER BY id;
DECLARE @id INT;
DECLARE @loop_id INT;
SELECT @loop_id = ISNULL(MAX(id), 0) FROM #loop_ids;
WHILE @loop_id > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @id = id FROM #loop_ids WHERE loop_id = @loop_id;
    --Do stuff with @id
    SELECT @loop_id = @loop_id - 1; --Or SELECT @loop_id -= 1;
END;
```

Comment: I see you didn't use cursors, the query resultes should return somthing like 1-10 Id numbers, is this method is the right way to go for me ? thank you !

Comment: I don't like cursors.  If this was me, and I wanted a small loop that I knew would never get out of hand, I would do this.  Actually I would probably consider looping over a temporary table, as it's not as messy (don't have to worry about the loop counter moving in steps), but the same basic approach.